# Lots of updates but don't know if they are working

Tags: updates

I have been getting a lot(2+ per day) of Operating System Updates recently but since there is no info along with the updates I don't know if they are just failing to download and accumulating into a later one or something. The amount of notifications is starting to bother me. I won't mind if the updates are legitimate.

For apps there is a version number but not for OS updates. Is there any way to check updates that have been released?

Also, it would be nice if there was a small change log attached to each update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to the terminal prior to updating you can use

```
sudo apt list --upgradable
```

it will show you the list of packages that are available for update.